# Order of Operations in `before` and `describe` blocks in Mocha/Chai Node Tests

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mocha.js, chai

To try and understand the execution order of one of my Mocha tests (where I was seeing functions execute out of order), I created the following simple test case:

```
describe("methods", function () {
  before(async function () {
    console.log('---------- BEFORE ------------');
    let sum = 1 + 2;
    console.log('sum: ', sum);
  });
  describe("test case", async function () {
    console.log('---------- AFTER ------------');
  });
});
```

Again, all I wanted to check here was the order of operations. And sure enough, in this case, all that prints to the console is `------------ AFTER ------------`. The logging from the `before` block doesn't show up in the console at all.

Why is this? What am I missing here?

In my actual test case I use the `before` block to create and save a document. And then in the next `describe` block I look it up in the db. When I ran into issues where the document was being looked up before creation had happened I decided to do some simpler tests. Hence what you see above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of the "before" block is executed just ***before*** an ***IT*** block

try to execute this:

```js
describe("methods", function () {
  before(async function () {
    console.log('---------- BEFORE ------------');
    let sum = 1 + 2;
    console.log('sum: ', sum);
  });
  it('should be a test', function(){

    console.log('test');

  });
  describe("test case", async function () {
    console.log('---------- AFTER ------------');
  });
});
```

see this post for more:
https://gist.github.com/samwize/8877226